# Is $V=L$ a single first-order sentence?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is $V=L$, the axiom of constructibility, a single first-order sentence?

Since $V=L$ really stands for $(\forall x)(\exists \alpha)[\alpha \in \mathrm{On} \wedge x \in L_\alpha]$, so my question might as well be "is $x \in L_\alpha$ a single first-order formula?".

I was confused about this since prima facie the definition of $L$ involves arbitrary first-order formulas and a satisfaction predicate for them.  Of course one can appeal to the recursive definition by using Goedel's operations, but I am still unsure whether all the details work out.

Comment: Yes it's a $\Pi_2$ sentence. Although I won't attempt to write down the sentence in full detail since it's extremely long. I think it's fully written down in Devlin's book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a first-order statement.

Recall that the definition of $L_\alpha$ is an inductive definition. $L_0=\varnothing$, $L_{\alpha+1}=\operatorname{Def}(L_\alpha,\in)$ and for limit ordinals $L_\alpha=\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha}L_\gamma$.

It might seem that the successor definition is not "internal", but in fact it is. It uses the internal definition of truth,<sup>1</sup> so it is again another definition using complicated inductions.

Finally, remember that the replacement schema allows us to take an inductive definition, over *all* the ordinals, and replace it with a single first-order statement. Much like how induction is internalized in Peano arithmetic.

---

1. Remember that the way we define first-order logic related concepts is really by induction. We have notions of strings, and when a string is a term, etc.; and a notion of a structure, and an assignment function, and then a truth value (after assigning the free variables values, of course).

   But since this is really just a long long long list of inductions, and the core concept of "strings" is already easy to formalize *internally* (simply finite sequences from a fixed alphabet), we can write a definition for what the universe "thinks" is the set of strings, and formulas and so on.

   So all this collapses to a very complicated, very long, very uninteresting formula that we know that we can write.

Comment: To make matters even more explicit, you say that $y=L_\alpha$ iff there is a sequence $(t_\beta\mid\beta\le\alpha)$ such that $t_\alpha=y$, $t_0=\emptyset$, $t_\gamma=\bigcup_{\beta<\gamma}t_\beta$ for all limit ordinals $\gamma\le \alpha$, and $t_{\beta+1}=\mathrm{Def}(t_\beta,\in)$ for all $\beta<\alpha$. Of course, for the definiton to make sense, you need to argue there is a unique such sequence.

Comment: Right, that is true. And that is what I meant by saying that this is like induction is internalized in Peano arithmetic.

Comment: In a sense, it is even easier, since we can use sequences directly rather than having to code them through Diophantine tricks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on the usage of "the internal definition of truth"? (I believe you know why I'm confused about this point.)

Comment: @Pteromys: Did my footnote help?

Comment: Here's my idea: although $V$ cannot internally define truth about $V$, but it _can_ define truth about each $L_\alpha$, and you can use this to define the class $L$.  Am I right?

Comment: @Pteromys: Yes, that is the exactly the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

There are 15 very simple functions that generate $L$. See Schindler Set Theory textbook for more details.

Examples of these function are the pairing function, set difference function, cartesian product, etc.

Define a function $S$ which takes a set $x$ to it closure under these 15 functions.

Define

$S_0 = \emptyset$

$S_{\alpha + 1} = S (S_\alpha)$

For limits $\lambda$, let
$S_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} S_\alpha$

Then it can be shown that $L = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{ON}} S_\alpha$.

Since $S$ is the closure of a finite list of function, it may be more clear that $\alpha \rightarrow S_\alpha$ is definable using the usual transfinite recursion.

This is similar to Godel and Jensen approach to constructibility.